# Why in "ant -?" targets are written in this way: [target [target2 [target3] ...]]?

Tags: ant, cmd

Why when you type

```
ant -?
```

in cmd, targets are written in this way?

```
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]
```

Why not like this?

```
ant [options] [target] [target2] ... [target3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a second target if you don't have the first - the target you supply would be the first. So this notation `[target [target2 [target3] ...]]` should be read as follows:

- you can have an optional target.
- if you do have a target, you could optionally have a second target.
- if you have two targets, you could optionally have a third target.
- etc...

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer! It's a really good explanation!